# Problem with Chrome/FireFox - Unable to Embed windows media player in ASP.NET

Tags: video, embed, wmp

I am trying to play a .wmv video in browser using asp.net 3.5.

This is my code

```
<object id="mediaplayer" type="video/x-ms-wmv" classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" width="500" height="500">
                    <param name="url" value="file:///C:/winvideo-ITPro-BuildAndPublishDataCubeToSSAS2008.wmv" valuetype="ref" type="video/x-ms-wmv">
                    <param name="animationatStart" value="1">
                    <param name="transparentatStart" value="1">
                    <param name="autoStart" value="1">
                    <param name="ShowControls" value="0">
                    <param name="ShowDisplay" value="0">
                    <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="0">
                    <param name="playcount" value="99999">
                    <param name="clickToPlay" value="1">
                     <param name="autoRewind" value="1">
                    <param name="displaysize" value="0">
                    <param name="stretchtofit" value="1">
                    <param name="enableContextMenu" value="0">
                    <param name="uiMode" value="none"></object>
```

I am able play this in IE but not in Chrome / FireFox.

I also installed plugin of Windows Media player for FireFox from

http://port25.technet.com/pages/windows-media-player-firefox-plugin-download.aspx

Please help me to solve this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used this to show wmv in Firefox.

```
<EMBED type="video/x-ms-wmv" width="416px" height="320px" autostart="False" URL="./Movie/Pljacka.wmv" enabled="True" balance="0" currentPosition="0" enableContextMenu="True" fullScreen="False" mute="False" playCount="1" rate="1" stretchTofit="False" uiMode="3">
```

The you can check browser by:

```
var browser = Request.Browser.Browser.ToLower();            
        if(browser == "ie")
        {
            pnlIE.Visible = true;
        }
        if (browser == "firefox")
        {
            pnlFirefox.Visible = true;
        }
```